# Create ArrayList of mp3 files in res/raw folder of Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using following code to play media file from my res/raw file, and it's working fine. But, I have 20 mp3 files in my res/raw folder How should I create ArrayList of mp3 files in res/raw folder?

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music_file);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

below is my complete code; I ma not able to play second audio file,

```
public class Datadetail extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context context;
TextView txtname;
TextView txtaarti;
String[] itemname;
int position;

ImageButton buttonPlay;

int[] songlist = {R.raw.ganesh_aarti, R.raw.durga_aarti};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.data_detail);


Intent i = getIntent();

position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
itemname = i.getStringArrayExtra("itemname");

txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
txtname.setText(itemname[position]);

txtaarti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
txtaarti.setText(Aarti.aartitxt[position]);


final MediaPlayer[] mPlayer = {MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist[0])};


buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (position==0) {
            mPlayer[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ganesh_aarti);
            mPlayer[0].start();
        }
        if (position==1){
            mPlayer[1] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.durga_aarti);
            mPlayer[1].start();
        }


    }


});
```

}

Comment: What should be in the ArrayList?

Comment: mp3 files example, R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2 etc..

Comment: So what is your problem with creating an Integer ArrayList and adding some integer values?

Comment: I have created an array int[] songlist = {R.raw.file1, R.raw.file2 , R.raw.file3}, but when I am using it in my Media Player it says  cannot resolve method create MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist);

Comment: Please put all code in your post. It's unreadable now. And where is your ArrayList instance? You created an integer array. That's something different. It should be `MediaPlayer.create(this, songlist[nr]);`. Who told you that MediaPlayer accepts a list?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void listRaw(){
   Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
        int resourceID=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);
        mArrayList.add(resourceID);
   }
}
```

After this you have every music files in one arraylist, play them accordingly :)

Comment: Thanks Jayanth, I am new to Android development, where should I put this code in onCreate or outside it ? and what should be done to use this in MediaPlayer do I have to use MediaPlayer.create ?

Comment: put that in oncreate

yeah same code but one difference is you need to iterate through arraylist and give value from arraylist

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, mArraylist(i));

Comment: make it as a global variable if you want and use it.